# Relocating <input> images top

Tags: html

I'm trying to make the image **stick.png** be next to **bigButton.png** but also directly under $15. Currently its got a 400px gap between $15 and **stick.png**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>$15 - Arsenal Clicker</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h1 align="center">Arsenal Clicker</h1>
<h1 align="center">$15</h1>
    <input type="image" id="bigButton" onclick="click()" src="Images/bigButton.png" height="500">
    <input type="image" id="stick" onclick="purchaseStick()" src="Images/stick.png" height="100">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now that the align and height attributes have been obsolete for many years

Comment: What do you mean? @Rob

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete I mean exactly what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to wrap your inputs with div,like I did with `.card-actions`, and use the CSS below to better align them. Hope this helps you solve the problem.

Good luck.

```css
/* added this */
.card-actions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<h1 align="center">Arsenal Clicker</h1>
<h1 align="center">$15</h1>
<div class="card-actions"><!-- added this -->
    <input type="image" id="bigButton" onclick="click()" src="Images/bigButton.png" height="500">
    <input type="image" id="stick" onclick="purchaseStick()" src="Images/stick.png" height="100">
</div><!-- added this -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it with the following CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;

}

.center {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
   padding: 10px;

}
```

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;

}

.center {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
   padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>$15 - Arsenal Clicker</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<div class="container">
<h1 align="center">Arsenal Clicker</h1>
<h1 align="center">$15</h1>
<div class="center">
    <input type="image" id="bigButton" onclick="click()" src="Images/bigButton.png" height="500">
    <input type="image" id="stick" onclick="purchaseStick()" src="Images/stick.png" height="100">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That just centered the two images for me. I'm trying to move stick.png up 400px cuz its smaller than bigButton.png and thus next to the bottom right of bigButton.png. I'm trying to move it to the top right of bigButton.png. Any ideas?